# Reverse-lookup words based on word vectors using amazon sagemaker / blazingtext model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

After training an deploying a model using blazingtext algorithm ... it is straightforward to obtain word-vectors for given words.

as demoed in this example -- https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_word2vec_subwords_text8

we can call the sagemaker.RealTimePredictor.predict function with the given word as the payload data and it will return the word vector

Now I want to be able to implement some basic NLP use cases like ... suggest a similar word, or Man-Woman+King = Queen

(for a different implementation using gensim see https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/)

To do this I would need to be able to call a function that takes a vector as input and returns the matching/nearest word/s from the embedding.

Is this even possible using the sagemaker sdk? I spent hours looking through the sagemaker api documentation (which was not easy to find or navigate) and I am still not sure if this is even possible

Comment: I do not think sagemaker SDK / blazingtext provides these features. 

However, it seems the model artifacts are gensim compatible so we could potentially use that route to get this functionality

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html

(see reference to Gensim in the "Model artifacts and Inference" section)

Answer (score 1):

You can install fasttext on your instance. then use the nn-function on your .bin-file which was created by your blazingtext model. e.g.:

```
fasttext nn SageMaker/vectors.bin
```

see [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html#nearest-neighbor-queries) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, SageMaker BlazingText does not support this feature. However, SageMaker supports K-NN algorithm (K Nearest Neighbor) which can be useful. You can build your word vectors using BlazingText and then train a K-NN classifier using those as your features. That'll give you the desired functionality. 
P.S. I am one of the developers for the BlazingText algorithm on SageMaker.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was to import gensim module and load the vectors.txt from the model artifacts generated by blazingtext

This way you do not even need to create a inference endpoint -- you can just use your notebook instance to work with your trained model

```
# download your model artifacts from s3 to notebook instance
!mkdir /tmp/model
!cd /tmp/model && aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/prefix/blazingtext-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx/output/model.tar.gz .
!cd /tmp/model && tar -xvzf /tmp/model/model.tar.gz

#install gensim on notebook instance
!pip install gensim

#use gensim in python code
import gensim, logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/model/vectors.txt', binary=False) 

word_vectors.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])

word_vectors.doesnt_match("breakfast cereal dinner lunch".split())
```

The only limitation i have come across so far is that if you have trained your model using "subwords=True" expecting to get word vectors for subwords or misspelled words, the gensim model does not seem to be able to return word vectors for out-of-vocabulary (OOV) words